# Even after adding "gem 'rails-controller-testing'" rails testing still throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have been having a problem with `assert_template` in rails. When running `rails t` it gives me an error message:

> NoMethodError: assert_template has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it, add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.

After adding `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to the Gemfile and running `bundle install` everything worked great.

However, when using a different computer and using `git pull` to sync the repository it doesn't work. Instead it just shows the same error as above.

Comment: After repo sync and bundle, right?

Comment: you did push to your repo after adding that to the Gemfile correct

Comment: probably he didnt git commit push to repo before pulling it on another computer

Comment: Yes... I've checked and gem 'rails-controller-testing' is in both Gemfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember there's two Gemfile files. There's Gemfile, which you edit, and then there's Gemfile.lock. You add something to the Gemfile manually, you then run bundle install, which will lock the version. You edit the Gemfile directly, but the Gemfile.lock is a system managed file that you don't touch. Make sure you commit and push them both after adding a Gem :D